# Data reading in Fortran

Tags: matlab, fortran, binaryfiles

EDIT: I am Making this just a question about the Fortran and will start a new question about converting to MATLAB.

ORIGINAL:

I am working on a project and am trying to port some old Fortran code into Matlab.  I have almost no Fortran experience so I am not quite sure what is going on in the following code.  The Fortran code is simply for interpreting data from a binary file and I have made some decent progress at porting stuff into MATLAB but have got stuck at the following part:

```
  IMPLICIT NONE

  DOUBLE PRECISION      SCALE

  CHARACTER*72          BLINE
  CHARACTER*72          DATA_FILE_FULL_NAME
  CHARACTER*6           DATA_FILE_NAME

  CHARACTER*4           CH4, CH4F
  REAL*4                RL4
  EQUIVALENCE          (RL4,CH4)

  CHARACTER*2           C2
  LOGICAL               LFLAG

  c2='69'
  LFLAG=.TRUE.

  DATA_FILE_FULL_NAME='./'//DATA_FILE_NAME//'.DAT'

  OPEN(UNIT=20, FILE=DATA_FILE_FULL_NAME, ACCESS='DIRECT',
 .     RECL=72, status='OLD')
    READ(20,REC=1) BLINE
    CH4f=BLINE(7:10)
    call flip(4,lflag,ch4f,ch4)
    SCALE=RL4

  RETURN
  END  

c   ..................................................
    subroutine flip(n,lflag,ch1,ch2)
c   ..................................................

  integer*4        n, i
  character*(*)    ch1, ch2
  logical          lflag

  if(lflag) then
    do i=1,n
      ch2(i:i)=ch1(n-i+1:n-i+1)
    enddo
  else
    ch2=ch1
  endif

  return
  end
```

What I am stuck with is getting the correct value for `SCALE` because I am not exactly sure what is happening with the `RL4`.  Can someone explain to me why RL4 changes value and what process changes it so that I can put this process into MATLAB?

Comment: It doesn't seem `RL4` should change its value from your code. It seems to be in fact undefined.

Comment: That is what I thought too @VladimirF; however it does change, and apparently gives the correct answer because this is an excerpt from code that is used by many different people.

Comment: Probably not a complete excerpt.

Comment: Ah, I just caught this at some point the following is called in the code `EQUIVALENCE          (RL4,CH4)`.  I have added this line into the code.

Comment: I suspected exactly that.

Comment: So, it seems to me that the equivalence declaration makes `RL4` and `CH4` point to the same block of data, so by calling `RL4` after defining `CH4` it is essentially just casting the data that was stored in the `RL4`-`CH4` memory location to the `RL4` format instead of the `CH4` format.  Does this sound correct @VladimirF?

Comment: yes (12 more to go...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code probably does change of [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) - the byte swap. The `equivalence` means that the equivalenced variables share the memory and you can treat the 4 bytes read from the file as a number after the byte swap.

The four bytes are therefore interpreted as a four byte real `RL4` and converted to a `double precision` value `scale` after that.

The byte swap is done only when the logical `lflag` is true. That will probably be when the byte order of the file is not the same as the machine native byte order.

In Matlab you can probably use http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/swapbytes.html .

Just read the 4 byte floating point number and swap the bytes if necessary.

Comment: Don't play with any `ch4f` anything in Matlab, just use the function `swapbytes`.

Comment: Ok, I realize now that the way I asked my question wasn't very good so I will make this one just about the fortran and accept your answer and then I will ask a new question about converting to MATLAB.  I have tried the swap bytes and it did not work out to the correct answer again.